# Reorganize multiple rows in a new table with more columns

Tags: sql, excel

I have a table that looks like that:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
| Club     | Role     | Name     | Lastname | Email                    |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
| Porto    | 1        | Peter    | Pan      | peter.pan@mail.com       | 
| Porto    | 2        | Michelle | Obama    | michelle.obama@mail.com  |
| Monaco   | 1        | Serena   | Williams | serena.williams@mail.com |
| Monaco   | 2        | David    | Beckham  | david.beckham@mail.com   |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
```

and i want to get a table like that:

```
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| Club     | Role 1 Name     | Role 1 Lastname | Role 1 Email                    | Role 2 Name     | Role 2 Lastname | Role 2 Email                    |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| Porto    | Peter           | Pan             | peter.pan@mail.com              | Michelle        | Obama           | michelle.obama@mail.com         |
| Monaco   | Serena          | Williams        | serena.williams@mail.com        | David           | Beckham         | david.beckham@mail.com          |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+
```

where the persons with different roles in each club puts in the same row.

I would ideally like to find a way to do that in Excel, but i am not sure if its possible. If not, SQL code would also help a lot.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: thanks for the fast comment, i have now edited the post and put the tables there.

Comment: Looks much better!

Comment: But what's the expected result if a club has only one person, or 3 or 4 persons?

Comment: some of the roles can only have 1 person having them, some other roles can be more that have them and i would like to have different columns for them, role3-1, role3-2 etc. But its not the crucial point. The important thing is to get the role1 and 2(which can be only one person per club) in the right columnt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I could come up with for an excel formula. Hopefully it can push you in the right direction.

This formula is assuming that your first table exists at the range A1:E5 and the second table exists at the range G1:M3. It is also assuming that the second table's column names are just repeating without the Role number attached to the front of it (same as the first table). This formula is an array formula, so you have to make sure to do CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when inputting it.

```
{=INDEX($A$2:$E$5,
  MATCH(1,($G2=$A$2:$A$5)*((FLOOR((COLUMN() - COLUMN($H$1) ) / 3,1) + 1)=$B$2:$B$5),0),
  MATCH(H$1,$A$1:$E$1,0))}
```

The first part is using the `INDEX` forumla which pulls data from the range suppled ($A$2:$E$5) based on the row and column numbers supplied by the following `MATCH` formulas.

The first `MATCH` is supplying the row number for when the result of the lookup array section is equal to 1. I am checking two conditions, the first is to check for the "Club" name `($G2=$A$2:$A$5)` and the second is to check for which "Role" we are currently on `((FLOOR((COLUMN() - COLUMN($H$1) ) / 3,1) + 1)`. This is using the `FLOOR` function to round the result down to the whole number and dividing by the number of columns (3 in this case: Name, Lastname, and Email).

The final `MATCH` is pulling the column number based on the header names from both tables. If you wanted to incorporate the changing names of the roles in the column headers, you could change this part to something like this:

```
 {=INDEX($A$2:$E$5,
  MATCH(1,($G2=$A$2:$A$5)*((FLOOR((COLUMN() - COLUMN($H$1) ) / 3,1) + 1)=$B$2:$B$5),0),
  MOD(COLUMN() - COLUMN($H$1),3) + 3)}
```

I am adding 3 to the end of the mod because of the original range that was selected for table 1. The columns that we want to pull start at location 3 in the range.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in Oracle Sql, there's a nice approach in analytical sql.
To convert/swap rows to columns or columns to rows, we can use Pivot or Unpivot operators.
In you example use below query to covert data as you like,

```
select * from 
(
with all_roles as
(select 1 role from dual union all
select 2 role from dual),
ddata as
(select 1 c_role, 'porto' club, 'peter' fname,'pan' lname,'peter.pan@mail.com' email from dual union all
select 2 c_role, 'porto' club, 'Michelle' fname, 'Obama' lname,'michelle.obama@mail.com' email  from dual union all
select 1 c_role, 'monaco' club, 'Serena' fname, 'Williams' lname,'serena.williams@mail.com'  email from dual union all
select 2 c_role, 'monaco' club, 'David' fname, 'Beckham' lname,'david.beckham@mail.com'  email from dual ) 
(select role, club, fname,lname, email from ddata,all_roles
where all_roles.role=ddata.c_role)) all_data
pivot ( 
  max(fname) fname,
  max(lname) lname,
  max(email) email
  for role in ( 1 role1, 2 role2 )
)
order by club;
```